# Create "edit" link in Review Suggested Edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

Recently I suggested an edit for a question that fixed several typos/grammar mistakes in the original question.

Immediatelly after hitting "Save Edits", I realized I had missed one typo. I went into the Review Suggested Edits page looking for a link to emend my suggested edit, but I could not find any.

Coincidentally, I clicked the "edit" link on the question once again to verify that the name of the action button on the next page was "Save Edits" (in order to write the sentence above), and I realized I could amend my suggested edit through there. Perhaps this functionality should be made more obvious in the Review Suggested Edits page.

Comment: I disagree. My reflex the first time it happened to me was to click on edit again right away, to discover that we can continue modifying an edit for a few minutes after it's been submitted. Clicking edit again to make an edit to the edit you just edited seems pretty straightforward and intuitive, doesn't it?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier the issue is that an URL such as http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12345 represents Suggested Edit #12345. The expected behavior (consistent with other rich, application-like websites) is to have functionality regarding #12345 exposed at that specific URL.

Moreover, this feature request could actually be expanded to include other actions such as deleting a suggested edit that is currently pending moderation (in case the user regrets suggesting it).

Comment: There again, I'll have to disagree. The page you link (apart from being broken) is directing towards the **review** queue. From which all relevant actions (rejecting, approving, improving) are already present depending on the context (namely when **reviewing** edits, which you will be able to do past 2k rep). **Editing** a post is relevant to the place where you can see the post, not it's suggested edit.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is really worth implementing in the review page. As for me, if I didn't know how to improve my suggested edit, I'd search for this link not on the review page, but on the page I made an edit.

However I agree with you that some clarification about your ability to improve  your suggested edit would be great. E.g. the banner "Thanks for edit" can be modified in this way:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed] (link to review page). During this time, you can [improve your edit] (link to editing page).